# Likes and Dislikes

Tags: gramática

This topic in Spanish is difficult and conflicting due to the grammatical foundation of natives of the various Spanish countries . So... I've reverted to this forum for professional assistance. Can you tell me which sentence below is correct and why, grammatically. Thank you in advance.

---

1. Me **gusta** el supermercado y la cafetería.

OR

2. Me **gustan** el supermercado y la cafetería.

Answer (score 1):

According to [DPD item 4.1.a)](https://www.rae.es/dpd/concordancia), the plural is correct but the singular is also possible if both nouns are conceived of as a unit. Suppose someone asks you:

- ¿Qué parte del centro de compras te gusta más: el supermercado y la cafetería, o las tiendas y los juegos?

You can answer:

- Me gusta el supermercado y la cafetería. (La parte del centro de compras que más me gusta es el sector compuesto por el supermercado y la cafetería.)

If two infinitives are used (4.1.c), then only the singular is correct:

- Me gusta ir al supermercado y tomar algo en la cafetería.

> 4.1. Sujeto de varios elementos en singular unidos por una conjunción copulativa. Debe tenerse en cuenta lo siguiente:
>
> a) Si los elementos coordinados se refieren a entidades distintas, el verbo va en plural: «Su voz y su gesto han hecho nido en mi corazón» (Matos Noche [Cuba 2002]); «En el patio crecían un magnolio y una azalea» (Mendoza Ciudad [Esp. 1986]); pero **si dichos elementos se conciben como una unidad, de la que cada uno de ellos designa un aspecto parcial, el verbo puede ir también en singular: «El desorden y la algarabía es total»** (Leñero Mudanza [Méx. 1979]); en ese caso es frecuente que solo lleve determinante el primero de los elementos coordinados: «La dirección y realización corrió [...] a cargo de Manolo Bermúdez» (Díaz Radio [Esp. 1992]). **El verbo suele ir asimismo en singular cuando el sujeto va pospuesto y los elementos coordinados son sustantivos abstractos o no contables, especialmente si aparecen sin determinación: «Me gusta el mambo y el merengue»** (GaRamis Días [P. Rico 1986]); «Solo me queda ánimo y tiempo para responderle lo que sigue» (Proceso [Méx.] 20.10.96).
>
> b) Si los elementos coordinados se refieren a una misma cosa o persona, el verbo irá necesariamente en singular: «La actriz y cantante está bastante molesta» (Universal [Ven.] 17.4.88).
>
> c) **Si los elementos coordinados son gramaticalmente neutros, como infinitivos, oraciones sustantivas o pronombres neutros, el verbo va en singular**: «No creo que sumar y restar sea lo suyo» (Sierra Regreso [Esp. 1995]); «Le gusta que la quieran y que la apoyen» (Tiempo [Esp.] 3.12.90); «Ni aquello ni esto hubiera sido posible» (Abc [Esp.] 25.1.85); pero si los elementos neutros coordinados se conciben o presentan en el enunciado como realidades diferenciadas, contrastadas o enfrentadas, el verbo irá en plural: «Informar y opinar son los dos fines específicos y diferenciales del periodismo» (MtzAlbertos Noticia [Esp. 1978]).

Comment: Oh okay. I understand this but how do I teach this to beginners of the language because it can be very confusing... I'll have to find a way or so...However thanks for explaining further! Much appreciated.

Comment: You should teach them the general rule: plural subject, plural verb. If they are curious and clever enough, you can explain the rest as exceptions to the general rule.

Comment: Lol good suggestion @Gustavson but I need to understand the full concept of using me gusta and me gustan in all contexts. Some are very confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the correct one. In Spanish the subject and the verb must concord in number (i.e. singular or plural). Since the subject is here plural (el supermercado y la cafetería), the verb must be in plural, **gustan**.
Having said this, however, you will hear very often the first option in informal conversations.

Comment: Oh okay I understand very well. This really makes sense...the grammatically correct way and the informal way. Thanks a lot for clarifying this! :)

Comment: It is not so easy: "me gusta reir y cantar"  is the formal and correct way  and "me gustan reir y cantar" is not fomal nor correct.  Moreover, "Me gusta Juana y Elena" could be formal and correct  if the two girls is  a recognizable group (e.g., a singer duo).

Comment: @Fran Oh no I fully understood what (Leo) said and I understand what you're trying to convey to me but remember those other factors you are mentioning I  know for a fact and understand those already. You will notice I was very specific with my question...it was an either/or question requesting an explanation why the choice. I already understand the other factors in the topic of likes and dislikes. Thank you all again for your help. I got the answer and explanation I was looking for.

Comment: I believe I didn't phrase my comment to (Leo) properly but I understood the concepts well. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @CarmelaF  Why the singular for different and unrelated  things like in  "me gusta el mar y la montaña"? Because really  is not  "me gusta[n] el mar y la montaña" but "me gusta el mar y [me gusta] la montaña". That is, the second verb is omitted and deduced from the context.  Therefore,  one could  say "me gusta la jarra y los vasos" ( "me gusta la jarra y [me gustan] los vasos") but never  "me gusta los vasos y la jarra". In our mind,  the verb concordance is  always maintained.

Comment: @Fran myy...this is really a complicated topic...I don't fully grasp what you're explaining... but I have a problem with (Me gusta la montaña y los vasos) when los vasos is a plural word. I can't teach this to beginners because it's even complicated for me to understand the full context of when to use me gusta and me gustan. Wow!

Comment: @CarmelaF It is  verb phrase ellipsis in a compound sentence like when an Englishman say "You might do it, but I won't."  instead of  "You might do it, but I won't **do it**."  In "La jarra me gusta y los vasos me gustan" you should not search for a concordance between of the first verb with the second subject, and the same apply to "Me gusta la jarra y me gustan los vasos", right?  Well, with the ellipsis is the same: "La jarra me gusta, y [second verb removed] los vasos" or "me gusta la jarra y [second verb removed] los vasos".

Comment: @CarmelaF Anyway, as single sentence with verb in plural is indeed better.